# DB2 Select Character Issues

Tags: java, mysql, db2

I am trying to select data from a DB2 database managed by another person so I can insert it into my SQL database managed by me for data manipulation.  I am using a java program to do this and the program has tested successfully on test data.  However, I am getting errors because of strange symbols in the db2 data.  Here is my error log.

```
Incorrect string value: '\xC2\x97D #5...' for column 'Name' at row 1
java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xC2\x97D #5...' for column 'Name' at row 1
INSERT INTO `Temp_Equipment_Inventory`.`PC_Table10i` SET `Account_No`='1019TJ148001',`Inventory_No`='569931',`Building_No`='0060',`Location`='CLASSRM',`FYYR_No`='2004',`Cost`='635.00',`Name`='MICROPHONE LAVALIER WIRELESS  (ISCÂD #5290)                 SHURE MODEL ULXP14/85                                       ',`CDCATY`='   ',`CDSRCE`='M',`FLDCAL`=' ',`CDACQN`='G',`FLOWNR`='Y',`FLSHAR`=' ',`CDDELT`='00',`CNYTDT`='00',`NOPURO`='6870607-01 ',`NOPIMO`='01',`CDPREI`='E',`Original_Amount`='155.00',`Serial_Code`='0309040351          ',`CDCOMP`=' ',`NOCHECK`='680146 ',`CDCOMM`='3651400',`Last_Update`='2008-07-18',`CDDEPT`='148',`Room_No`='0300 ',`Date_Scanned`=NULL,`Date_Acquired`='2004-03-09',`Manufacturer_Name`='SHURE       ',`Expiry_Date`=NULL
```

As you can see, the Name column has the data (ISCÂD #5290) with the funny Â throwing the error.  However, when I browse the data in the db2 table, this Â does not appear.

I have set the mysql tables to UTF-8 unicode ci.

I cannot edit the db2 database since it is not managed by me.

What else can I do to try and get around this Â symbol in my data?

Comment: What's the platform the DB2 database is running on?  Also, can you figure out the _source_ row that you're getting the error from, to figure out what it actually contains?

Comment: The code actually contains MICROPHONE LAVALIER WIRELESS  (ISC&#8212;D #5290)                 SHURE MODEL ULXP14/85                    for that section when I convert the binary to Text.  The db2 is running AS400 platform.  So the problem is occuring with the &#8212 and java.String not understanding that symbol.

Comment: The `&#8212;` is the html encoding for an 'em-dash' (like a '-', but different).  This suggests that the string in the database was being output to a web-page directly.  I haven't been able to figure out how that is getting mis-translated to the 'Â' character (they don't appear to share any relevant datapoints).  What does Java actually think the line is _before_ the insert (the error you're getting is likely being generated from the database, so, we may have multiple translations)?

Comment: when you browse the DB2 data what does appear (if not the A)? you say you are having DB2 select character issues, but the error in your log is from an insert statement. maybe the problem is in java or mysql?

Comment: Aren't encoding issues always fun... Are you testing on a Windows machine? Like X-Zero said, that entity code is for the em dash. But what you see in your exception are the respective codes for Â (C2) and em dash (97) in the [cp1252 encoding](http://unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/WINDOWS/CP1252.TXT). What I'm saying is: maybe you're seeing an Â for no other reason than that the stack trace is printed out to a console in some incompatible encoding. This isn't the root of the issue, but it might obfuscate it.

Comment: @vikrantislav - What's actually appearing in the DB2 database is `&#8212;`.

Comment: Come to think of it, how are you building the statement? Is it a prepared statement that you fill the parameters for, or do you simply  concatenate a String?

Comment: Can it be related to your IDE? Maybe it is overriding your encoding?

Comment: My second suggestion is looking at your jdbc connection definition try to add: jdbc:mysql://server/database?characterEncoding=UTF-8 for my first suggestion i.e. Netbeans adding this line to configuration file: -J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you 're using UTF-8 for the encoding you could try to add the following parameters in your jdbc connection url

```
<connection_url>?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

You could replace it with your encoding, if UTF-8 is not suitable for your needs.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

\xC2\x97 is the UTF-8 byte sequence for encoding unicode character — (the em dash)

It seems like the java code has converted the UTF-8 data to UTF-16 (the native java encoding) without decoding it. Then the insert is failing because the UTF-16 code points for the characters Â and em dash are actually invalid UTF-8 code points.

So perhaps the solution is to decode what is read in DB2 with the UTF-8 codec to obtain the proper UTF-16 representation before doing the insert, or if the target database requires UTF-8 encoding, then perhaps the best solution is not to go through java.String at all but just read and write binary data.

Answer (score 1):

> What else can I do to try and get around this Â symbol in my data?

1. What is your test data? Is it tested for the Â -cases?
2. Make a dummy copy of a similar database or take a sample of the database at the location of the problem. Replace the character with `\^A`.

I still believe that the problem is in your java -code that you are not parsing things right. Try python or simpler code with Java to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Skip the Java program and use the DB provided tools to move the data. For DB2 use `db2 export` to get your data out into a flat file. Then use `mysqlimport` to load it into MySql.